# Should an OFFLINE database be SET EMERGENCY before dropping?

Tags: sql-server, offline

As a rule before dropping a database I, SET OFFLINE, for 30 days before dropping it.  If there is anything that was missed and the database is still needed, I can SET ONLINE quickly for a full restore.

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE database_name
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

If you drop a database while it is offline, the files stay on the server forever unless you purposely go clean them up.  Assuming the you have taken whatever backups you want and are sure you want to completely drop the database on the server, you put it back online then drop it.

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE database_name
SET ONLINE

DROP DATABASE database_name
GO
```

The database comes fully back online then gets dropped.  Might it be a better practice to SET EMERGENCY before dropping?  Depending on many variables, in theory when you go online a missed OLTP connection could access the database between ONLINE and DROP.

Using SET EMERGENCY, grants ["READ_ONLY to members of sysadmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) and brings the database far enough online so that files on the server are deleted. At least with my limited testing on SQL2014

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE database_name
SET EMERGENCY

DROP DATABASE database_name
GO
```

If a missed OLTP (or anything) manages to connect to the database between ONLINE and DROP you would have deleted any record of it with the drop.

Might it be a better practice with an OFFLINE database to SET EMERGENCY before dropping?  If you are using T-SQL is it to quick for any possible connection to occur?

If you are using the Delete Option on SSMS, even best case between online and delete, is going to measurable in seconds. Should this always be avoided?

Comment: Don't disagree with @Kin but if you are that concerned about access post offline/pre-drop, why don't you revoke connect for the DB users in the database, set DBO to an unused sysadmin login that is disabled and then read-only the database? Any drop scenario, you should have not only the scripted actions in place for the change, but also a backout script, which is minor to mearly grant connect again and change DBO back.

Comment: If you revoke connections for the database, and you need to bring it back online you would need to restore those connections.  If I am not the one on call in the middle of the night when the application owner suddenly realizes they were wrong about not needing that database.... Well the on-call person is going to need to call and wake me up, so I can tell them all the things they need to undo, or so I can fix them.  Online vs offline with no changes, is an easy recovery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** make sure you have a final full backup of the database before you drop it, just incase if you need to restore.

Normally, [`EMERGENCY` mode](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-4-using-emergency-mode-to-access-a-recovery-pending-or-suspect-database/) is used for getting your database out of corruption.

You are right, that `EMERGENCY` mode will allow only sysadmin members and the db will be read-only - nothing gets written to T-LOG.

I would suggest that get the database to `RESTRICTED USER` and then drop it.

e.g. `ALTER DATABASE your_db_name SET RESTRICTED_USER` or `READ_ONLY`

Note: This is just my preference which distinguish between `EMERGENCY` mode --> use to take DB out of corruption vs `RESTRICTED_USER` or `READ_ONLY` --> give it chance to breathe before you drop !

Answer (score 1):

When you drop a database set to `EMERGENCY` mode it will leave the log files behind.
`RESTRICTED_USER` doesn't help if the users have the **db_owner** or **dbcreator** role.
So I would go with `ALTER DATABASE your_db_name SET READ_ONLY` as well.